# Return a valid value to the caller using a static method in Java

Tags: java, methods, return

this is my school homework. I spent a whole day to think about it, but failed. I'm looking for help on stackoverflow.

The question is, each time prompting the user to enter four integers and displaying the appropriate message, until the user enters the value 0 when prompted for n, which is a signal to terminate execution. Also, I need include a static method:

```
int getAndVerifyInput (String userPrompt, int lowerBound, int upperBound)
```

that prompts the user for a value, verifies that it is within the desired range(if-else is correct as shows below). Re-prompting and re-entering if necessary, and returns a valid value to the caller.

Here is my code.

```
class AssignmentTwo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int n,i,j,k;    
            n = getAndVerfyInput("Enter size of circle, n", 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            i = getAndVerfyInput("Enter first point(i)", 0, n);
            j = getAndVerfyInput("Enter second point(j)", 0, n);
            k = getAndVerfyInput("Enter third point(k)", i, j);

            if (n>0 && i>=0 && i<=n && j>=0 && j<=n && k>=0 && k<=n && i!=j &&
                    ((k<=i&&i<j)||(i<j&&j<k)||(j<k&&k<=i)))
                System.out.println("\nk lies on the arc from j to i when moving clockwise on a circle of size n.");
            else
                System.out.println("\nk does not lie on the arc from j to i when moving clockwise on a circle of size n.");
        }

    static int getAndVerfyInput(String userPrompt, int lowerBound, int upperBound)  // i j is lowerBound and upperBound
        {
            System.out.println(userPrompt);

            int result;

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
            result = keyboard.nextInt();

            return result;
        }
}
```

My question is that i have four variables (n,i,j,k), but in getAndVerifyInput only has two variables, I don't know how to put IF-ELSE into getAndVerifyInput method.

My professor's hint: The first parameter to method getAndVerifyInput is a string, for example, the first time the method is called, which is to get the size of the circle n, the second time it's called, which is to get i. etc for j&k.

The method itself should display the first parameter as a prompt to the user, and then input the value from the user, and finally verify that's within bounds before returning the value to the calling code (main).

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: i have added to the question. Thank you!

Comment: What is getAndVerifyInput  method supposed to do?

Comment: I add to the question. Than you Balwinder!

Comment: I still don't see a question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated question, you need to verify that user input remains within `lowerBound` and `upperBound`. If this is the question, then you can try changing the existing `getAndVerfyInput`to following:

```
static int getAndVerfyInput(String userPrompt, int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{


    int result;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

    do{
        System.out.println(userPrompt);
        result = keyboard.nextInt();    

    } while (result < lowerBound || result > upperBound);



    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps